# Issue while inserting the user in liferay

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have created a form which has basic user details and on clinking of the Save button I am inserting the user details in the "USER_" table by calling the `UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(....)`. Now the user is creating with out any issue. But I am not able to see some form field parameters in `UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(....)` method like (Title, Gender and Date Of Birth). Now how can I save this values. Please give me some suggestions that how can I insert the following fields (Title, Gender and Date Of Birth) at the time of user creation.

Comment: These fields are part of model named as Contact, you have to store contact model against your user to save them.

Comment: How can I save them in Contact table. Is there any api method available. Please suggest some solution

Comment: Have a look at  `com.liferay.portal.service.ContactLocalServiceUtil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay uses `com.liferay.portal.model.Contact` entity to store the contact information.

Use `com.liferay.portal.service.ContactLocalServiceUtil.addContact` method to create the contact. Significant parametres:

- `userId` - Id of the user that is creating the contact. You can use  `PortalUtil.getUser` method to get the current user from a request.
- `className` - "com.liferay.portal.model.User".
- `classPK` - Id of the new user that the contact is created for.

Comment: What is "className" attribute here and how ca I get the className field value?

Comment: There're two ``ContactLocalServiceUtil.addContact`` methods. The first accepts instance of ``Contact`` model, the second has individual parameters with contact values. I was referring to the second method and its first three parameters. The other parameters are rather obvious. For ``className`` parameter, use the String value from the answer I provided.